# Can’t find how to edit push notifications title and content within code - Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I’ve bought application template and I can’t figure out in code where to change push notification title and content (Firebase as message provider platform). Developer is unreachable and I can’t go further with project.

For example instead push “You have new message” I want to have “You have ONE new message”; I searched through whole code without success.

Also - is there any way push notifications can be translated to multiple languages?

### Edit

There is no Firebase Extending Service in source file related to messaging, only to phone authentication.

Sample of code:

```
package com.innomalist.taxi.driver.activities.splash

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId
import com.gun0912.tedpermission.PermissionListener
import com.gun0912.tedpermission.TedPermission
import com.innomalist.taxi.common.components.BaseActivity
import com.innomalist.taxi.common.interfaces.AlertDialogEvent
import com.innomalist.taxi.common.networking.socket.interfaces.ConnectionError
import com.innomalist.taxi.common.networking.socket.interfaces.Namespace
import com.innomalist.taxi.common.networking.socket.interfaces.RemoteResponse
import com.innomalist.taxi.common.networking.socket.interfaces.SocketNetworkDispatcher
import com.innomalist.taxi.common.utils.AlertDialogBuilder
import com.innomalist.taxi.common.utils.AlertDialogBuilder.DialogResult
import com.innomalist.taxi.common.utils.AlertDialogBuilder.show
import com.innomalist.taxi.common.utils.AlerterHelper.showError
import com.innomalist.taxi.common.utils.CommonUtils.isGPSEnabled
import com.innomalist.taxi.common.utils.CommonUtils.isInternetDisabled
import com.innomalist.taxi.common.utils.MyPreferenceManager.Companion.getInstance
import com.innomalist.taxi.driver.R
import com.innomalist.taxi.driver.activities.main.MainActivity
import com.innomalist.taxi.driver.activities.profile.ProfileActivity
import com.innomalist.taxi.driver.databinding.ActivitySplashBinding
import com.innomalist.taxi.driver.networking.http.GetRegisterInfo
import com.innomalist.taxi.driver.networking.http.Login
import com.innomalist.taxi.driver.networking.http.LoginResult
import com.innomalist.taxi.driver.networking.http.RegistrationInfo
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric
import java.lang.Exception

class SplashActivity : BaseActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySplashBinding
    private var SIGN_IN_ACTIVITY = 123
    private var startRequested = false
    private val permissionListener: PermissionListener = object : PermissionListener {
        override fun onPermissionDenied(deniedPermissions: List<String>) {
            show(this@SplashActivity,"It is not possible to run the app as driver without location permission. Given that you have already didn't approved location access you can now go to settings and enabled it. Then you can close app and open it again to access.", AlertDialogBuilder.DialogButton.OK, AlertDialogEvent {
                checkPermissions()
            })
        }
        override fun onPermissionGranted() {
            if(getInstance(applicationContext).token != null) {
                tryConnect(getInstance(applicationContext).token!!)
            } else {
                goToLoginMode()
            }
        }
    }
    private val onLoginClicked = View.OnClickListener {
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(listOf(PhoneBuilder().build()))
                        .setLogo(R.drawable.logo)
                        .setTheme(currentTheme)
                        .build(),
                SIGN_IN_ACTIVITY)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        isImmersive = true
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (getString(R.string.fabric_key) != "") {
            Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())
        }
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_splash)
        binding.loginButton.setOnClickListener(onLoginClicked)
        checkPermissions()
    }

    private fun checkPermissions() {
        if (!isGPSEnabled(this)) {
            show(this, getString(R.string.message_enable_gps), AlertDialogBuilder.DialogButton.CANCEL_RETRY, AlertDialogEvent { result: DialogResult ->
                if (result === DialogResult.RETRY) {
                    checkPermissions()
                } else {
                    finishAffinity()
                }
            })
            return
        }
        if (isInternetDisabled(this)) {
            show(this, getString(R.string.message_internet_connection), AlertDialogBuilder.DialogButton.CANCEL_RETRY, AlertDialogEvent { result: DialogResult ->
                if (result === DialogResult.RETRY) {
                    checkPermissions()
                } else {
                    finishAffinity()
                }
            })
            return
        }
        TedPermission.with(this)
                .setPermissionListener(permissionListener)
                .setDeniedMessage(getString(R.string.message_permission_denied))
                .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .check()
    }

    fun tryConnect(jwtToken: String) {
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnCompleteListener {fb ->
            SocketNetworkDispatcher.instance.connect(Namespace.Driver, jwtToken, fb.result?.token ?: "") {
                when (it) {
                    is RemoteResponse.Success -> {
                        startMainActivity()
                    }

                    is RemoteResponse.Error -> {
                        when (it.error) {
                            ConnectionError.RegistrationIncomplete -> {
                                runOnUiThread {
                                    showRegisterForm(jwtToken)
                                }
                            }

                            else -> {
                                runOnUiThread {
                                    goToLoginMode()
                                    try {
                                        it.error.showAlert(this)
                                    } catch (exception: Exception) {

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showRegisterForm(jwtToken: String) {
        GetRegisterInfo(jwtToken).execute<RegistrationInfo> {
            when(it) {
                is RemoteResponse.Success -> {
                    runOnUiThread {
                        preferences.driver = it.body.driver
                        preferences.services = ArrayList(it.body.services)
                        val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                }

                is RemoteResponse.Error -> {
                    //it.error.showAlert(this)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if(preferences.token != null) {
            tryConnect(preferences.token!!)
        }
    }

    private fun startMainActivity() {
        if (startRequested) return
        startRequested = true
        val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun tryLogin(firebaseToken: String) {
        goToLoadingMode()
        Login(firebaseToken).execute<LoginResult> {
            when(it) {
                is RemoteResponse.Success -> {
                    getInstance(applicationContext).driver = it.body.user
                    getInstance(applicationContext).token = it.body.token
                    tryConnect(it.body.token)
                }
                is RemoteResponse.Error -> {
                    showError(this, it.error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun goToLoadingMode() {
        binding.loginButton.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun goToLoginMode() {
        binding.loginButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_ACTIVITY) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.getIdToken(false).addOnCompleteListener {
                    tryLogin(it.result!!.token!!)
                }
                return
            }
            showError(this@SplashActivity, getString(R.string.login_failed))
            goToLoginMode()
        }
    }
}
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

Let me explain you nature of message: There's TWO apps - driver and passenger: when passenger do something, for example - ask for near driver, all drivers nearby recieves push message - You have one new request. Also, for example - when payment made - passenger recieves message - Payment settled. Wher's this stored, for God's sake :)

**GRADLE FILES**

There are THREE modules inside of app - common, driver & rider, and FOUR gradle.build files.

**Common Module Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.0'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
    api 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    api 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-beta01'
    api 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    api 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:6.2.0'
    api('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    api('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    api 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.6.2'
    api 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.4'
    api 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.2'
    api 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.9.2'
    kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.2'
    api 'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:2.1.0'
    api 'com.github.tylersuehr7:empty-state-recyclerview:1.0.4'
    api 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.4'
    api 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:2.2.0'
    api 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    api 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:5.0.0'
    api 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.2.2'
    api 'com.github.stfalcon:chatkit:0.3.3'
    api('com.stripe:stripe-android:12.8.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    api 'com.github.MAXDeliveryNG:slideview:1.1.0'
    api 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.7.1'
    api 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.3.1'

    //noinspection LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8
    kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0'
    api 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.0'
    api 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.3.61"
    api 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3'
    api 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3'
}
```

**Driver Module Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.ldrive.taxi.driver'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 35
        versionName '3.0.9'
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    api project(':common')
    api 'com.diogobernardino:williamchart:3.3.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**Passenger/Rider Module Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ldrive.taxi.rider"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 35
        versionName "3.0.9"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        dexOptions {
            jumboMode true
        }
    }
    if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS")) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    api project(':common')
    implementation 'com.github.Innomalist:floatingsearchview:0.3'
    implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0')
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**PROJECT GRADLE**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for a class that **extends** FirebaseMessagingService. This is where all FCM service is set.

### Edit

This is how I customise my notifications in my own app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BOBusinessHomePage.class);           
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

Notification notification =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "0")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.business_icon)
    .setContentTitle("A client has posted a new review in your business page!")
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build();
mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Try to search "Notification" or any type of template similar to above in your project.

Or, try to search callback  method named `onMessageReceived()`.

### Explanation

By default, your app won’t display any FCM messages it receives while it’s in the foreground, so when you send a message there’s no guarantee your users will actually see that message.

To act on the messages your app receives while it’s in the foreground, you’ll need to extend the FirebaseMessagingService, override the onMessageReceived method, and then retrieve the message’s content using either getNotification or getData, depending on whether you’re working with data or notification messages, or both.

Comment: I will try to share all related to FMS in code here, but all is ordinary (not at PC at the moment, will share little bit later), but no definition of notification message at all. Is it possible to have notif. data stored elsewhere than in source code of app?

Comment: There is no Firebase Extending Service in source file related to messaging, only to phone authentification service.

Comment: Hi and sorry for the late respond it was a night time here. So to customise with push notification using firebase you have to override callback method named : "onMessageReceived". If you don't find this method in your app its mean that FCM is not set yet. Let me know if it help u :)

Comment: Hello. Maybe I search for wrong item here, just thinking out loud - this is not Firebase (there is no onMessageReceived() method). Let me explain you nature of message: There's TWO apps - driver and passenger: when passenger do something, for example - ask for near driver, all drivers nearby recieves push message - You have one new request. Also, for example - when payment made - passenger recieves message - Payment settled. Wher's this stored, for God's sake :)

Comment: I assume the drivers get the push notifications for a new request while the app in background. can you share your "build.gradle" file in your question? i am trying to find out who is your third party provider for push notifications service.If you solve it already let me know how :)

Comment: I just edited main question and added gradle code, please review it. Yes, all notifications are in background of app. Thank you

Comment: Tnx for sharing. By reading your common module gradle code i see that you are using Firebase Cloud Messaging api. So you are using Firebase for push notifications ("api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'"). I need to see your full project to give u a better answer. sorry:) I am curios about it so it will be nice to know if you solve it and how.

Comment: It’s not a problem. Where and how to send you full code? Will be happy to have “partner” because I exhausted my eyes, can’t look at code anymore :)

Comment: yea why not :) which VCS  are u using?I hope GitHub. just give me a read permission. My user is BenSiso.

Comment: I just placed download link for code from GDrive - it is at the bottom of the main post/question. Thank you. PS. Just write when you're downloaded code, so I can remove download link...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208128/discussion-between-eager2learn-and-ben).